# how to update a json file in python

Tags: python, json

im a beginner in python, i would like to know how to update a json file in python by adding another attribute named cat which is a specific category like sport,education,music...ect

any help would be appreciated thank you

here's an example of my json file data:

before :

```
{"tweet_id":"1261276320878788609",
"date":"Fri May 15 12:44:42 +0000 2020",
"raw_text":"برنامج وطني لدعم المبدعين في مواجهة #كورونا",
"geo_source":"user_location",
"location":{"address":
{"country":"Tunisia","country_code":"tn","state_district":"غزالة","county":"العرب","state":"Bizerte"},
"response":
"{'place_id': 235309103, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'relation', 'osm_id': 7124228, 'boundingbox': ['37.105957', '37.2033466', '9.4739053', '9.6124953'], 'lat': '37.1551868', 'lon': '9.54834183807249', 'display_name': 'العرب, غزالة, Bizerte, Tunisia', 'class': 'boundary', 'type': 'administrative', 'importance': 0.45, 'icon': '/data/nominatimimages/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png','address':{'county': 'العرب', 'state_district': 'غزالة', 'state': 'Bizerte', 'country': 'Tunisia', 'country_code': 'tn'}}",
"geohash":"snwg37buskzd","query_term":"arab","lon":9.54834183807249,"lat":37.1551868},
"user_friends_count":61,"user_description":"I love UAE and his great leadership",
"user_created_at":"Wed Oct 09 11:41:41 +0000 2013",
"user_screen_name":"SikandarMirani",
"user_id_str":"706377881",
"user_verified":false,
"user_statuses_count":50804,
"user_followers_count":946,
"user_location":"Dubai United Arab Emirates"}
```

after :

```
{"tweet_id":"1261276320878788609",
"date":"Fri May 15 12:44:42 +0000 2020",
"raw_text":"برنامج وطني لدعم المبدعين في مواجهة ##البيان_القارئ_دائما",
"geo_source":"user_location",
"location":{"address":
{"country":"Tunisia","country_code":"tn","state_district":"غزالة","county":"العرب","state":"Bizerte"},
"response":
"{'place_id': 235309103, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'relation', 'osm_id': 7124228, 'boundingbox': ['37.105957', '37.2033466', '9.4739053', '9.6124953'], 'lat': '37.1551868', 'lon': '9.54834183807249', 'display_name': 'العرب, غزالة, Bizerte, Tunisia', 'class': 'boundary', 'type': 'administrative', 'importance': 0.45, 'icon': '/data/nominatimimages/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png','address':{'county': 'العرب', 'state_district': 'غزالة', 'state': 'Bizerte', 'country': 'Tunisia', 'country_code': 'tn'}}",
"geohash":"snwg37buskzd","query_term":"arab","lon":9.54834183807249,"lat":37.1551868},
"user_friends_count":61,"user_description":"I love UAE and his great leadership",
"user_created_at":"Wed Oct 09 11:41:41 +0000 2013",
"user_screen_name":"SikandarMirani",
"user_id_str":"706377881",
"user_verified":false,
"user_statuses_count":50804,
"user_followers_count":946,
"user_location":"Dubai United Arab Emirates"
"cat":"(any category)"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it is to load json file into the program, add parameter and then dump it.

```
import json
with open("myfile.txt") as my_file:
    my_json_dict = json.load(my_file)
    my_json_dict["New key"]="New value"

with open("myfile.txt', "w") as my_file:
    json.dump(my_json_dict,my_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any library that would let you just partially update an existing file. The usual way is to load and parse your json file into a python object

```
with open('foo.json') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
```

then update your object whichever way you want:

```
obj['cat'] = ...
```

then write back the file:

```
with open('foo.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f indent=4)
```